# Upload old folders as versions in git

Tags: git, version-control

So I have been using folders for version control so far and I really want to use Git going forward. 
I have ~ 20 folders in the format `projName_YYYYMMDD` format. Does Git allow to convert these older version in folders as its commit history?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just overwrite the contents and commit them one at a time in your git repo.

```
## Overwrite Previous Folder with Next Folder
git add -A
git commit -m 'commit message here, perhaps the date from the folder'
```

Comment: I already have current version in that repo.. So I guess I would have to start all over again from the beginning..